# deno (Deno.command) Uncaught Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. (os error 193)

Tags: deno

Running these ["Install from source"](https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter/tree/master) instructions, I get an error:

```
error: Uncaught Error: %1 is not a valid Win32 application. (os error 193)
```

Specifically the instructions include:

- Run `deno task build`
- Where the `build` task is configured in `deno.json` as:

  - `"build": "deno run --allow-all --unstable './tasks/build.ts'",`
- Where the `build.ts` eventually runs code like this:
- `await Deno.run({ cmd: ["./node_modules/.bin/esbuild"] }).status()`

I use Windows machine, and the command `"./node_modules/.bin/esbuild"` works from both my Windows cmd and my Git Bash.

I have `deno --version`:

```
$ deno --version
deno 1.33.4 (release, x86_64-pc-windows-msvc)
v8 11.4.183.2
typescript 5.0.4
```

I saw [`Deno.run` is deprecated](https://deno.land/api@v1.33.4?s=Deno.run), so I used `new Deno.Command(...)` instead, I still get the error.

I tried playing with certain [CommandOptions](https://deno.land/api@v1.33.4?s=Deno.CommandOptions) to specify the `cwd` and set `windowsRawArguments` to true, but it doesn't work.

I tried checking other similar questions

- [This Python question, the issue is 32 bit vs 64 bit DLL's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477956/error-193-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application), and a [similar question on x86 vs x64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68781616/1175496) I don't think that's my problem
- [This Python question, the solution is to use `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25652750/1175496), but I don't think Deno has the equivalent option

**EDIT**

I understand the difference between the different commands. I understand how [the esbuild.cmd file emulates the esbuild "shebang" line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585966/node-modules-bin-package-cmd-file-in-node-js)

```
node_modules
 > .bin
     > esbuild      #This is for Unix, has shebang
     > esbuild.cmd  #This is for Windows
     > esbuild.ps1
```

That doesn't explain why Deno can't run the `esbuild`.
My Python can run the `esbuild`, without needing to use `esbuild.cmd` (notice I use [`shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45500091/1175496)). **Without** `shell=True`, I get the same error as with Deno. **So maybe my question is better restated as, "how can I do the equivalent of Python's `shell=True` in Deno?")**

```
subprocess.call('"./node_modules/.bin/esbuild"', shell=True)
```

My Windows command line (after I open it) can run  the `esbuild`, without needing to use `esbuild.cmd` (I have Git Bash installed, but see the screenshot, I am using Windows command prompt)
[image: windows command prompt can run the bash script esbuild file]

When I run `cmd.exe "./node_modules/.bin/esbuild"`, it does not work, I get an error:

```
'"./node_modules/.bin/esbuild"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

When I use Node instead of Deno, I get the same error:

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');
const esbuild = spawn('"./node_modules/.bin/esbuild"', {shell:true}); 
esbuild.stderr.setEncoding('utf8'); 
esbuild.stderr.on('data',_=>console.error(_))     

>> '"./node_modules/.bin/esbuild"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Ultimately I guess the workaround is "stop trying to behave like Linux, you're using Windows, accept that and **just use the esbuild.cmd file**"

But I'm still curious about why some languages/subprocesses can run the `esbuild` (Python shell=True), but others cannot (cmd.exe run with args, Deno, Node with shell=True). It's small silly detail with [lots of nuance](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_spawning_bat_and_cmd_files_on_windows), but maybe not significant enough to remain a question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node\_modules/.bin/package.cmd file in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37585966/node-modules-bin-package-cmd-file-in-node-js)

Comment: @jsejcksn I think that's related; I think it teaches me why the `esbuild.cmd` file is there, and so I can just run that file as a "workaround". I'm still curious why I can't run the `esbuild` script directly from Deno (I edited my answer to show in Python I can run `esbuild` directly, in Windows command prompt I can run `esbuild` directly, but not in Deno, nor in Node..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, note the command I was trying to run:

`new Deno.Command("./node_modules/.bin/esbuild").output()`

Following the suggestion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40390500/1175496), I changed my command to use the `esbuild.cmd` file. It worked, no error...

`new Deno.Command("./node_modules/.bin/esbuild.cmd").output()`

This suggestion wasn't obvious to me because my **Windows command line *was*** able to execute this:

`"./node_modules/.bin/esbuild"`

But my `Deno.Command(...)` was **not** able to execute the above, until I changed the command to use the `esbuild.cmd` instead. I'm not sure why...

**EDIT**

I tried to edit my answer to show why I think this is a workaround. It's a fine workaround, I should accept that I'm running Windows, so `cmd` files are meant for me. But in my question I show how Python can run the `esbuild` file directly, and so can Windows command prompt, so why not Deno? (or Node?).